# How i can get the distance and duration between current location and destination location using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to calculate the distance between two locations current location of a user and destination location I have the latitude and longitude of the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this question doesn't belong directly to Android though to a Google Map library usable in Android so you may refer here for full details and implementation process:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro